# Should questions marked as dupes award badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Just curious on what you all think. Should badges be awarded for whatever the requirements are on duped questions?

Comment: Is this even an issue...?

Comment: Aren't badges supposed to indicate something good done? If questions are closed, that totally negates the point of badges.  Why award badges to commemorate nothing special?

Comment: Honey Badgewhores like me

Answer (score 3):

Sure, why not?

Comment: Because dupes are literally worse than every bad thing ever forever combined, *duh*. Why else would we interpret views on them so widely?